# How can I get number of connection per clients in Redis Cluster

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, redis-cli

From Redis CLI I can see number of connected clients by running `client list`.

[image]

Now I want to see number connection per client(by addr or id) made to Redis Cluster.

Is there any way to do so. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `redis-cli --cluster call <ip>:<port> CLIENT LIST` and have a shell script to grep/sort/aggregate the results per client address/id.